# Authenticating against Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server with SAML Assertion in Authorization Code Flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

**Situation:**

- An up and running Spring Boot Service that acts as OAuth2 Authorization Server, granting JWT Access Tokens.
- Only `password` `grant_type` supported ATM (looking up the credentials in the database).

**Problems/Goals:**

- Some customers want to connect their own SSO Server (AD + SAML 2) to this application so their users can login with their company credentials.
- We would like to only do the Authentication using SAML 2 and then grant a JWT to these users, so we don't need to change all our clients.

According to [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-20) and [this Blog Post](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Using+OAuth+2.0+from+a+Web+Application+with+SAML+Bearer+Assertion+Flow) it seems to be possible using the `authorization_code` Grant Type.

So doing a Request like this:

```
 POST /token.oauth2 HTTP/1.1
 Host: as.example.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=authorization_code&
 code=vAZEIHjQTHuGgaSvyW9hO0RpusLzkvTOww3trZBxZpo&
 client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth
 %3Aclient-assertion-type%3Asaml2-bearer&
 client_assertion=PHNhbW...[omitted for brevity]...ZT
```

Which can return a JWT Token containing an OAuth Access Token. This would be fine, but I have a hard time to figure out how to implement this using [Spring Security OAuth2](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-oauth) and the existing SAML 2 Extensions/Libraries for Spring Security.

Here my specific Questions:

1. *spring security oauth* offers the `AuthorizationCodeServices` Interface which can implement and configure to handle OAuth Authenticaiton Requests with the `grant_type=authorization_code`. I'm not quiet sure how to create the `OAuth2Authentication` instance to return in `consumeAuthorizationCode(String)` since I can't persist it when `createAuthorizationCode`is called (as in the `InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices`) because as I understand the SAML/OAuth2/Authorization Token Flow, `consumeAuthorizationCode(String)` will never be called. Maybe `AuthorizationCodeServices` is also not the correct approach?
2. The best SAML 2 Implementation for Spring I found was the [Spring Security SAML Extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/). But I find the reference documentation rather confusing. I can't seem to figure out if the Extension can be used to just verify the incoming token against various IdPs or this can only be used standalone. Maybe someone already has experience there and can tip me off?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @homaxto hey, funnily just two weeks ago we started working on the SAMLv2 integration in our spring boot oauth2 resource server again! Spring security now integrated SAMLv2 into their lib ... we may write a blog post about it. Will post it here if we got it working.